# easy way to copy/move already created AWS stuffs from current VPC to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Could you please suggest easy way to copy/move already created AWS stuffs from current VPC to another ?

Comment: No, we can't, because it depends on service by service.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "easy" way but you can use different tools to import existing resources and deploy them to different VPCs.

- There is a free tool called **Former2** (https://github.com/iann0036/former2) **which can be used to scan existing resources and produce outputs**. These outputs can be used to deploy new resources. I tested this tool and it seems to be quite intuitive to use to gather information about existing resources and produce outputs in different template languages (Cloudformation, Terraform, CDK, Stroposphere, Pulumi).
- **Terraform** can be used to import existing resources to the current state and after that copy resources to configuration. Future versions of Terraform will be able to also update the configuration. To use terraform you must know every resource you want to import and use import command with their ids. Terraform **does not support nested imports** so importing vpc does not add subnets or other resources to the state but they have to be imported separately.
- I think **CloudFormation** has also import feature but specific resource template must be written beforehand and submitted during the import. This is not an easy or fast way to copy resources but should work and as an end product there should a template which can be used to deploy resources to another VPCs.